# No pyvenv.cfg file, for all projects

Tags: python, pycharm, python-venv, pyvenv

I downloaded scripts to learn coding python. when "pip install" or try to launch any python code, it shows `No pyvenv.cfg file`

I tried re-installing "pycharm" and "python" but it does not work.

Comment: If I am not mistaken, [`pyvenv.cfg` files are related to Python virtual environments](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html?highlight=pyvenv.cfg). Maybe something went wrong with a Python virtual environment that you are trying to use.